# Load pipe delimited CSV data having " (double quote) in one of the column in hive

Tags: csv, hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql, hive-serde

I have data as below:-

```
Rollno|Name|height|department
101|Aman|5"2|C.S.E
```

Taking all the columns as string.
When I am loading above data in hive I am getting extra quote at start and end as below:-
Rollno:-"101
Name:-Aman
Height:-5"2
Department:-C.S.E"
Can anyone help me with the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Specify your separator such as:

```
val df = spark.read.option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").option("sep", "|").csv("test.csv")
df.show(false)

+------+----+------+----------+
|Rollno|Name|height|department|
+------+----+------+----------+
|101   |Aman|5"2   |C.S.E     |
+------+----+------+----------+
```

Comment: Can't this be handled using csvserde in HQL??

Comment: Then, split and get from array. But your csv loading is already messed up, the quote is not escaped well. So, it is somehow corrupted.

Comment: Thanks @Lamanua!Yes the way you shared I am able to read data correctly but when I am saving this data frame to another hdfs location the column height having quote itself is getting saved as "5"2".How can I handle this so that quotes get escaped and only 5"2 got written to the other hdfs location.

Comment: When I write this df to csv again then it save with the escape `\ ` `df.write.option("header","true").csv("test")`